# Pandas: How to assign one column value to a variable, based on another column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame, for which I want to store values from the `keyvalue` column into a variable, based on the value of `keyname`.

Example DataFrame:

```
keyname     keyvalue
A           100,200
B           300
C           400
```

Expected output:

```
v_A = [100, 200]
v_B = 300
v_C = 400
```

Comment: Please add more details, so we can help you. With the current description your question is not clear.

Comment: use keyname as variable and keyvalue as value and store value in a variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close, what you need is dictionary with keys and values, because [concept of strings variables in python is not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables):

```
d = df.set_index('keyname')['keyvalue'].to_dict()
```

Comment: TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable

Comment: @ShivamPatel - so you need `d = df.set_index('keyname')['keyvalue'].to_dict()` only?

Answer (score 3):

While this is a more verbose approach, it's posted to demonstrate the basic concept for assigning `keyvalue` values to a `list` variable, based on the value of `keyname`.

```
v_A = df.loc[df['keyname'] == 'A', 'keyvalue'].to_list()
v_B = df.loc[df['keyname'] == 'B', 'keyvalue'].to_list()
v_C = df.loc[df['keyname'] == 'C', 'keyvalue'].to_list()
```

Output:

```
['100,200']
['300']
['400']
```

Comment: SyntaxError: can't assign to literal

Comment: (SyntaxError in comment above does not apply to the current (edited) answer.)

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest two options..

1. Convert to a dictionary.. that will give you them as key value pairs, if that is what you want.

   ```
   df.set_index('keyname').to_dict()
   ```

output:

```
   {'keyvalue': {'A': '100,200', 'B': '300', 'C': '400'}}
```

2. Take a transpose and you will get them in columns of dataframe and then you can convert as list

   ```
   dft=df.set_index('keyname').T
   v_A=list(map(int, dft['A'][0].split(",")))
   v_B=list(map(int, dft['B'][0].split(",")))
   v_C=list(map(int, dft['C'][0].split(",")))
   print(v_A)
   print(v_B)
   print(v_C)
   ```

output :

```
   [100, 200]
   [300]
   [400]
```

Comment: I dont see why is better as culomns.. nd what that dictionary is better then jezreal answer?